Hint on examine the integrability?
How to examine the integrability of $f(x,y)=\left\{\!\!\!\begin{array}{c c}{{~x+y,}}&{{x,~y~\mathrm{are~rational},}}\\ {{~x-y,}}&{{\mathrm{other~cases.}}}\end{array}\!\!\right.$ on $[-1, 1]\times[-1, 1]$
I tried to divide it into two parts. When x, y are not both rational, then x-y should be continuous, so the variation can be controlled. When x, y are both rational, this part I have no clue how to control it.
Could you please give me a hint?

Let $g(x,y) = f(x,y) - x + y$ then $g(x,y)$ is almost zero everywhere, and its integral is zero,
See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Characterization_of_Almost_Everywhere_Zero.
Thus $g$  is integrable, and so is $f$

@ioveri I haven't learnt about Lebesgue measurement. I need a method not using Lebesgue measurement. :(

in that case, how is your integral defined?

Just Riemann integration of on $R^2$

then it's not integrable, because you can choose the sample points to be either all rationals or irrational, leading to two different result so the limit does not exist.

Why the result of Reimman integration doesn't equal to the result using Lebesgue measurement?

@Andrews Why they should be equal?

@Andrews the point of Riemann integral is that the choice of sample points shouldn't matter as the sub-intervals size get towards zero. This is true for continuous function or bounded continuous function with a finite number of discontinuities. However this function has an infinitely many discontinuities so the Riemann sums fail to converge

@ioveri But isn't it the content of Lebesgue Theorem?en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma Could it be that in this theorem the integration isn't Riemann integration?

To show that $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ it is enough to show it is not Riemann integrable on the subset $S= [0,1]\times [0,1]$.
Let $g(x,y) = x+y$ and $h(x,y) = x-y$ and note that $g(x,y) \geqslant h(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in S$. Consider any partition $P$ of $S$  with subrectangles $R_1, \ldots,R_n$. Since every $R_j$ contains points $(x,y)$ where both coordinates are rational and points where at least one coordinate is irrational, we have  $\sup_{(x,y) \in R_j}f(x,y) = \sup_{(x,y) \in R_j}g(x,y)$ and $\inf_{(x,y) \in R_j}f(x,y) = \inf_{(x,y) \in R_j}h(x,y)$.
It follows that the upper and lower Darboux sums of $f$ are given by
$$U(f,P) = U(g,P), \quad  L(f,P) = L(h,P),$$
and, thus, for upper and lower Darboux integrals we have
$$\overline{\int_S} f = \inf_P U(g,P) = \overline{\int_S} g, \quad \underline{\int_S} f = \sup_P L(h,P)=\underline{\int_S} h$$
Now finish by showing that
$$\overline{\int_S} g =1 \neq 0 = \underline{\int_S}h $$

Why $\overline{\int_{S}}{g=1}$ and $\underline{\int_{S}}h=0$?

@Andrews: Both $g$ and $h$ are continuous functions and, hence, Riemann integrable.  The upper and lower integrals coincide with the Riemann (double) integrals which are easy to compute.
